# What can I do with soaked beans that I can't use right away?

Tags: beans

I started soaking some dried black beans in water and salt in preparation to make *delicious* beans and rice tomorrow. However my wife has informed me that we have a previous engagement tomorrow and cannot have the beans.

So now I have soaking beans. They are soaking at room temperature. I don't think I can keep soaking them for another few days without turning them into mush. Can I remove and drain them and use them in a few days? Can I continue to store them in water?

What can I do to not waste my beans?

Answer (score 2):

**Cook the beans.**

Cook them low and slow.  Cook them now, or tomorrow, during your engagement.  I routinely cook black beans 12 hours overnight.  The longer you cook them the sweeter they will be.

Beans are one of those things that get better the day after.  Put the beans in the fridge after they are done and then you can eat them the day after tomorrow.   For breakfast!  Fry them in a pan and fry an egg in the middle of them.  That is what I ate for breakfast this morning (red beans, though).